# Load java.io.File At Runtime On Classpath

Tags: java, jaxb, schema

I have two jars (main.jar and schema.jar) and I need to read a schema file (located in src/main/resources/sample.xsd) from schema.jar in a class within main.jar.  main.jar has schema.jar on its classpath as a maven dependency. I'm able to find the sample.xsd file when I use the this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream, but I need a java.io.File.  What is the most memory efficient approach to supply the java.io.File parameter?

**main.jar:**

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("/resources/sample.xsd");

Sample sample = new Sample();
//set sample data here
 Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Sample.getClass()).createMarshaller();
    final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    final Schema s = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("/resources/sample.xsd"));
marshaller.setSchema(s);
    marshaller.marshal(Sample, XML);
```

Comment: Normally src/main/resources is a source root and in that case you should use getResource("/sample.xsd") instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`SchemaFactory#newSchema(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema%28java.net.URL%29) method instead.

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/sample.xsd");
// ...
final Schema s = schemaFactory.newSchema(url);
```

No need to massage the `InputStream` into a `File` which isn't nicely possible anyway (you could create a temp file, but that's plain clumsy). JAXB will under the covers grab the `InputStream` from the supplied `URL` by [`URL#openStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29).